# Flex: How do you import a .zip project?

Tags: apache-flex

Whenever you view a flex app and go to view source you can download a zip of the flex app. Once you do that how do you import it? I went to flex>import and I get to options import archive file I pointed that to the zip and it says its not a valid archive file. so I tried the other option import flex project folder, I extracted the zip and pointed it to that and it says its not a valid project folder...what am I supposed to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is one of my recent projects](http://joelhooks.com/examples/pipemachine/srcview/) that imports directly. It really depends on how the author exported it. If it isn't exported properly, then you will need to do the extra work to get it into Flex/Flash Builder.

If the project won't import directly simply extract it, create a new project named how you'd like, and drop the contents of the source file into the src file in the project you've created. Then, you simply need to right click the 'main' mxml/as file and 'set as default application'. Now it is ready for you to run/debug normally.

Comment: wow your right.... for some reason this used to not work for me.  It must have been related to the actual projects themselves and not the import wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to create a new Flex project, and then unzip your example Flex app code into the /src folder of that project.

I'm pretty sure the *Import archive file* feature expects proper metadata files in the archive which the "View Source" exported zip file does not contain.

Comment: This isn't correct. It depends on how they are exported.View source on all my projects gives an archive than can be imported as a "Flex Project" or "Existing Project"

Answer (score 0):

Some developers (incl. me) publish their flex app with all required project resources (html-template/, libs/, .actionScriptProperties, .flexProperties, .project). The only thing you need to do then is to extract the zip into your workspace and import the unzipped project folder via Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace.

If you are using the same version of Flex SDK, then it should be already compiled and ready to test/use, no configuration required!

Unfortunately, not all published apps provide those time-saving resources.

Answer (score -1):

@Tehnomaag your correct.  The import archive file only works if the person exported using that tool.... which I find is few and far between.  The export is really good if you need to include compiler settings with the zip file